# Foreach not giving me any result

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

**Hello guys!**

I'm trying to use a foreach cicle to show some images from my disk but something is getting wrong. It show and error saying

> **Message: Array to string conversion**
>    Line Number: 306

Here is my foreach cicle

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="row">
                {foreach $products as $product}
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <img class="card-img-top border-bottom" src="{$product.image}" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 class="card-title">
                                    <p class="text-dark">{$product.name}</p>
                                </h6>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="material-icons">local_grocery_store</i><span class="float-right mr-4">Adicionar ao carrinho</span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/foreach}
                </div>
            </div>
```

My error said the problem is on this line

```
$data['products'] = '.base_url(' . $this->Cart_model->get_img() . ').';
```

Also my model with get_img() is this

```
    public function get_img(){
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
        return $query->result();
    }
```

and this is my database

[Data base example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TImY.png)

Comment: `get_img()` returns the row from `SELECT * FROM products` so `$this->Cart_model->get_img()` is a whole array of data.

Comment: but SELECT images FROM products not solve the problem and only return a item from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is add `src="<?php echo base_url('{$product.image}'); ?>"` in the Views

```
<div class="row">
                    {foreach $products as $product}
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <div class="card h-100">
                                <img class="card-img-top border-bottom" src="<?php echo base_url('{$product.image}'); ?>" alt="" style="width:30px;height:30px;">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h6 class="card-title">
                                        <p class="text-dark">{$product.name}</p>
                                    </h6>
                                    <div class="text-danger"><b><span>{$product.price}€ </span></b><span class="text-secondary float-right"><del>{number_format((float)$product.price*1.5, 2, '.', '')}€</del></span></div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="material-icons">local_grocery_store</i><span class="float-right mr-4">Adicionar ao carrinho</span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/foreach}
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're using `base_url` to call the `model`, remove the `base_url` and then call the model. Like this -

```
$data['products'] = $this->Cart_model->get_img(); // returns array of objects
```

In your view file, use `foreach` to traverse the data then you'll have to do something like

```
<?php echo base_url()."path/to/folder/$product->table_image_column"; ?>
```

**View (in php)** `// this is how I'd do.`

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top border-bottom" src="<?php echo base_url()."your/path/$product->image"; ?>" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-title">
                    <p class="text-dark"><?php echo $product->name; ?></p>
                </h6>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="material-icons">local_grocery_store</i><span class="float-right mr-4">Adicionar ao carrinho</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

or if you're using any framework and don't want to mingle php in it. Use `foreach` in the controller itself and add `base_url()` to the image. You don't have to make any changes in the view for this-
**Controller**

```
$i= 0;
foreach($products as $product) {
    $products[$i]->image = base_url()."path/to/image/$product->image"; // change the products array with new values
    $i++;   
}
```

See if it helps you.

Comment: but how can i add base url later to get my images in database ? if i dont use base url it will to some strange path

Comment: it did not work, the answer was adding src="<?php echo base_url('{$product.image}'); ?>" to views

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I wrote in the first code `[view(in php)]` @RicardoMartins smh